# Performance and abstraction questions re: scraper for carfolio.com

Tags: performance, web-scraping, rust

I'm a new Rust programmer, primarily coming from Ruby experience.
I started working on a small project to scrape vehicle specifications from https://carfolio.com

I chose to write it in Rust and actually got the code working, but I had some questions regarding async, performance, as well as code organization and abstraction.

The general gist of my code is that it scrapes the [Carfolio specifications](https://carfolio.com/specifications) page for a list of automobile makes. It'll grab the name of the make, the country of the make, as well as the link to the make's page.

The make's page will have each of the make's models listed there. The next thing my code does is iterate thru the list of makes, and grab all the data from the makes' page for the models. This currently just includes the name of the model, the year, and the link to the models' details pages.

I haven't done the part of the details for the models, because I wanted to get some feedback on performance here, since this essentially is a 3rd level of a nested loop, and I want to take advantage of the `async` web requests I'm making to make it faster.

Here are the few files that comprise my project:

`src/main.rs`:

```rust
extern crate pretty_env_logger;
#[macro_use] extern crate log;

use scraper::html::Html;

mod carfolio;

fn main() {
    pretty_env_logger::init();

    carfolio::scrape();
}

async fn fetch_page(url: &str) -> Result<Html, reqwest::Error> {
    info!("Scraping HTML from {}", url);
    let resp = reqwest::get(url).await?;
    let body = resp.text().await?;
    
    Ok(Html::parse_document(&body))
}
```

`src/carfolio/mod.rs`:

```rust
mod make;
mod model;

pub(crate) fn scrape() {
    make::makes().unwrap().iter()
        .map(|make| model::models(make.to_owned()).unwrap())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
}
```

`src/carfolio/make.rs`:

```rust
use scraper::html::Html;
use scraper::Selector;
use scraper::element_ref::ElementRef;

const BASE_URL: &str = "https://carfolio.com/specifications";

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Make {
    pub name: String,
    pub country: String,
    pub url: String
}

fn divs(html: &Html) -> Vec<ElementRef<'_>> {
    let selector = Selector::parse("div.grid div[class^=\"m\"]").unwrap();
    html.select(&selector).collect()
}

fn extract_link(div: ElementRef) -> ElementRef {
    let selector = Selector::parse("a.man").unwrap();
    div.select(&selector).next().unwrap()
}

fn extract_url(div: ElementRef) -> String {
    let link = extract_link(div);
    let path = link.value().attr("href").unwrap().to_string();

    format!("{}/{}", BASE_URL, path)
}

fn extract_name(div: ElementRef) -> String {
    let link = extract_link(div);
    link.inner_html()
}

fn extract_country(div: ElementRef) -> String {
    let selector = Selector::parse("div.footer").unwrap();
    div.select(&selector).next().unwrap().inner_html()
}

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn makes() -> Result<Vec<Make>, reqwest::Error> {
    info!("Requesting Makes data");

    let html = match crate::fetch_page(BASE_URL).await {
        Ok(html) => html,
        Err(e)   => return Err(e),
    };

    let makes = divs(&html).iter().map(|div| {
        let url = extract_url(*div);
        let name = extract_name(*div);
        let country = extract_country(*div);
        debug!("Make: {} ({}) - {}", name, country, url);

        Make { name: name, country: country, url: url }
    }).collect::<Vec<Make>>();

    Ok(makes)
}
```

`src/carfolio/model.rs`:

```rust
use scraper::html::Html;
use scraper::Selector;
use scraper::element_ref::ElementRef;

const BASE_URL: &str = "https://carfolio.com";

use super::make::Make;

pub struct Model {
    pub make: Make,
    pub name: String,
    pub year: Option<u16>,
    pub url: String
}

fn divs(html: &Html) -> Vec<ElementRef<'_>> {
    let selector = Selector::parse("div.grid div.grid-card").unwrap();
    html.select(&selector).collect()
}

fn extract_data(div: ElementRef) -> ElementRef {
    let selector = Selector::parse("div.card-head a span.automobile").unwrap();
    div.select(&selector).next().unwrap()
}

fn extract_url(div: ElementRef) -> String {
    let selector = Selector::parse("div.card-head a").unwrap();
    let link = div.select(&selector).next().unwrap();
    let path = link.value().attr("href").unwrap().to_string();

    format!("{}/{}", BASE_URL, path)
}

fn extract_name(div: ElementRef) -> String {
    let selector = Selector::parse("span.model.name").unwrap();

    let data = extract_data(div);
    match data.select(&selector).next() {
        Some(inner) => inner.inner_html(),
        None        => "".to_string()
    }
}

fn extract_year(div: ElementRef) -> Option<u16> {
    let selector = Selector::parse("span.Year").unwrap();
    let alt_selector = Selector::parse("span.model-year").unwrap();
    let data = extract_data(div);

    match data.select(&selector).next() {
        Some(inner) => Some(inner.inner_html().parse::<u16>().unwrap()),
        None        => match data.select(&alt_selector).next() {
                         Some(inner) => Some(inner.inner_html().parse::<u16>().unwrap()),
                         None        => {
                             error!("Could not find year info in {:?}", data.inner_html());
                             None
                         }
                       }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn models(make: Make) -> Result<Vec<Model>, reqwest::Error> {
    info!("Requesting Models data for {}", make.name);

    let html = match crate::fetch_page(&make.url).await {
        Ok(html)  => html,
        Err(e)    => return Err(e),
    };

    let models = divs(&html).iter().map(|div| {
        let year = extract_year(*div);
        let name = extract_name(*div);
        let url = extract_url(*div);

        debug!("Model: {:?} {} {} - {}", year, make.name, name, url);
        Model {
            make: make.clone(),
            name: name,
            year: year,
            url: url
        }
    }).collect::<Vec<Model>>();

    Ok(models)
}
```

The biggest questions I have are:

1. The [reqwest](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest) library states that if I'm making multiple connections, I should instantiate a `reqwest::Client` and re-use that. How might I do that in Rust? Right now my `fetch_page` function doesn't do that, and I'm not even sure abstracting that as a function is worth anything, besides less LoC.
2. How might I take advantage of the `async`-ness `fetch_page` function? Currently, when I run the code, it's pretty clear that everything is running sequentially, and I know that with `async` I can probably get better performance than just running it like that.
3. Wondering about how I structured my code, whether having the `carfolio`, `carfolio::make` and `carfolio::model` modules are even worth it? To me it looks cleaner, but I'm not sure what the general organization of experience Rust developers would be.
4. Abstracting out all the `extract_*` functions... similar to question 3, looks cleaner to me, but not sure how experienced developers would do it.

Any other general feedback is greatly welcome as well!
Thanks in advance for your time!